# VS Code in WSL2: Python extension doesn't find references, definitions or dependencies in code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I am running a Python-Project in WSL2 using Visual Studio Code.
The extensions I have installed are:

- isort
- Pylance
- Python
- Python Debugger

all of them are specifically installed and enabled on WSL. I open VS-Code by starting a WSL shell, cd-ing to my directory and then typing `code .`. I don't understand why nothing seems to be working.

Code completion, complete syntax highlighting, jumping to function or variable definitions, finding references, etc. all of them don't work.
Syntax is partially highlighted but not completely.

I am using Python 3.10.2 as an interpreter installed in `/usr/local/bin`.

If I open my project on Windows instead, everything seems to be working fine.

Anyone who has similar issues?

Comment: Do you have the [WSL](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl) extension installed? Also refer to the documentation here. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl-tutorial, https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl

Comment: Yes the WSL extension is also installed

Answer (score 1):

Please downgrade or wait for the next fix to be released.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/206486#issuecomment-1973670490

Comment: Do you think this is related? In my case, code completion is not working probably, and only in WSL